# Generating random result based on previous result

Tags: python, random

I want to generate random result with weights based on the previous result.

I am generating random results with weights in the following manner

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
results = random.choices(a, weights=(
    (10, 20, 30, 30, 10, 6)), k=100)

print (results[0:100]
```

What I want to do is if results[n] = 1, the next result cannot be 6(i.e. it can be between 1 and 5).
I am new to this page and python. Any help would be useful

Comment: Why would a `1` exclude `6` from the next result? What happens for the other numbers?

Comment: and what should `6` be replaced with?

Comment: If the result is 1, I want to remove 6 just from the next result. Result can be 1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: Is that the only constrain, or are there more constrains for the other numbers (e.g. what should happen with the next result if `results[n] = 2`)?

Comment: if result[n] = 2, the next result can be be 1,2,3,4,5,6
only when it is 1, the next result cannot be 6

Comment: If the last value is 1, use a different set of weights where the weight for a 6 is 0. You haven’t said how the other weights might vary though.

Comment: The weight of 6 will become 0. The other weights will be 10, 20, 30, 30, 10. 

I want to generate 100 results where 1 is not succeeded by 6. There are no constraints as far as other combinations are concerned.

Comment: I think you need to iterate through one random choice at a time (`k=1` in your call to `random.choices` but with `N=100` calls) and then have an `if` statement that directs whether `6` is in your list of potential values. Alternatively you could make a longer list, remove cases of `6` if they follow a `1`, and then only use the first 100 values of your longer, pruned list. Personally, I would probably take the first option for simplicity unless there was a major performance issue compared to the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **[Kelly Bundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12671057/kelly-bundy)**'s suggestion from the comments:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
choices = random.choices(a, weights=(10, 20, 30, 30, 10, 6), k=100)
# print(choices)
for i, (prev, curr) in enumerate(zip(choices[:-1], choices[1:])):
    if prev == 1 and curr == 6:
        # print(f'Rerolled {i + 1}') 
        choices[i + 1] = random.choices(a, weights=(10, 20, 30, 30, 10, 0), k=1)[0]
print(choices)
```

**Example Output:**

```
[5, 4, 4, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 4, 3, 6, 4, 3, 4, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 1, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 5, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 4, 6, 4, 3]
```

---

You could change the corresponding weight for 6 to 0 for the next choice if the previous choice was a 1:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
choices = []
k = 100
i = 0
previous_choice_1 = False
while i < k:
    if previous_choice_1:
        choice = random.choices(a, weights=(10, 20, 30, 30, 10, 0), k=1)[0]
    else:
        choice = random.choices(a, weights=(10, 20, 30, 30, 10, 6), k=1)[0]
    choices.append(choice)
    previous_choice_1 = choice == 1
    i += 1
print(choices)
```

**Example Output:**

```
[6, 3, 3, 6, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 6, 1, 2, 2, 6, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 5, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 6, 4, 1, 5, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 6, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4]
```

Comment: Once a 1 is found then the results will never contain a 6 again no matter the previous result

Comment: Ok, whoops ty. Will fix.

Comment: I had upvoted. I don't know how it happened. My reputation is less than 15. So apparently I cant vote.

Comment: Oh yes. 6 should come again in the code

Comment: Thanks, guys fixed, I really wanted to optimize using `extend` rather than doing it one by one XD.